# How to conditions to comma separated JSON array object in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to get the hospital details filtered by the services. In the  `hospital` table there is a column `services` which contain comma separated ids of services, for example `["10", "12", "20"]`, and I want to filter those hospitals with service id 10 and 12. I am passing `["10", "12"]`. I need to query in Codeignaiter.

```
$this->db->select('tbl_hospital.*');
$this->db->from('tbl_hospital');
$this->db->where_in('tbl_hospital.services', ["10", "12"], false);
$this->db->get()->result();
```

I have tried this query but it is not working.

Comment: Are you using CodeIgniter 3 or 4? The method `where_in` doesn't exist in 4, so that could be your problem.

Comment: I am using  CodeIgniter 3. where_in is workin in another queries but here it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible issues with your code:

1. You're not assigning a variable to the result method.
2. In CodeIgniter 3, boolean values should be in uppercase letters, otherwise, it will be interpreted as a string and cause a query error.

This code should work for your needs:

```
$this->db->select('tbl_hospital.*');
$this->db->from('tbl_hospital');
$this->db->where_in('tbl_hospital.services', ["10", "12"], FALSE);
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
return $result;
```